# Abstracting over types of non-type template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to write a template that can deconstruct a type into a template with non-type template parameters along with its non-type template arguments. E.g., it would deconstruct `Array<5>` into `template<int> Array` and `5`, but would work generically for any type of non-type template parameter (integral types, pointers, member pointers, etc.).

First try, with template specialization:

```
template<typename T> struct foo { enum { n = 1 }; };

template<int x> struct bar { enum { n = x }; };

template<typename T, template<T> class X, T x>
struct foo< X<x> > { enum { n = x }; }; // here x must be of integral type, but that's just for testing

int main(int, char**) { return foo< bar<16> >::n; }
```

Clang 3.1 says:

```
test145.cpp:6:8: warning: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that can not be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
struct foo< X<x> > { enum { n = x }; };
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
test145.cpp:5:19: note: non-deducible template parameter 'T'                     
template<typename T, template<T> class X, T x>
                  ^
1 warning generated.
```

Second try, with a function template:

```
template<typename T, T x> 
struct box 
{ 
    static constexpr T value() { return x; }
};

template<typename T, template<T> class X, T x>
box<T, x> foo(X<x>);

template<int> struct asdf { };

int main(int, char**) { return decltype(foo(*(asdf<9>*)0))::value(); }
```

Clang says:

```
test150.cpp:12:41: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
int main(int, char**) { return decltype(foo(*(asdf<9>*)0))::value(); }
                                        ^~~
test150.cpp:8:11: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
box<T, x> foo(X<x>);
          ^
1 error generated.
```

GCC 4.7 says similar things.

Is this a fundamental limitation?

Bonus question: If it is, then is there any way at all to handle all of the infinite possibilities in a finite amount of code, even if it's less simple and generic code? (It gets difficult with e.g. pointers: for the same reason that you can't seem to write `template<T>` I don't think you could write `template<T*>` either.)

Please don't ask why I'm asking.

Comment: I must say : I do not understand what exactly you need

Comment: I believe one could summarize it as follows: Let `template<int> struct A {}`. Is it possible (and if so, how) to write a template `arg` such that `arg<Array<5> >::template_` is `template<int> Array`, `arg<Array<5> >::type` is `int`, and `arg<Array<5> >::value` is `5` (and of type `int`), and also make it so generic that every possible non-type template argument can be handled in this way.

Comment: That's basically it. Thanks for putting it more clearly than I could!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***The answer might come a little late...***

#### *Missed Try...*

*(see **Correct Answer** & **C++17 Solution** below)*

---

> This original answer is kept as a souvenir of my very first answer on SO.
> Not exactly a fail, one would say. But rather, a first missed try... ;)
> *Now, jump to the next horizontal line...*

I was searching for an answer to a related question when I came across this question. After having read it, I told myself: *"Humm... That's something I already did. And it worked. How did I do it exactly?!"*. And then, I continued searching for the answer to my question...

Today I felt like I should take a little time to propose a solution to this problem *(two actually)*.

As you already noticed, the problem comes from the fact that the compiler has no clue on how to deduce `T`. One can interpret the error message as *"Please, give me a little help on that `T`"*.

The first version I did that was working had the specialization of `foo` deriving from a class similar to `std::integral_constant`. Making `foo` derive from `std::integral_constant<T, x>` might have had help the compiler to figure out the type of `T`. *(or maybe MSVC -vs2019- had been a little nice with me)*

Anyway, meanwhile I found better solution. And there should have no way for the compiler not to be able to deduce the type of `T`, because, there is no need of a `typename T` parameter for the type of `x`...

---

Here it is: ***(C++17 Solution)***

```
template<typename T> struct foo {};

template<auto x, template<decltype(x)> class X>
struct foo<X<x>> {
    using            arg_type   = decltype(x);
    static constexpr arg_type n = x;
};

//template<int x> struct bar { enum { n = x }; };
template<int x> struct bar;

using bar_16            = foo<bar<16>>;
using bar_16_arg_t      = typename bar_16::arg_type; // int
constexpr auto bar_16_n = bar_16::n;                 // 16
```

Note that for this to work, it is not even needed for `bar` to be a complete type. A forward declaration *(like in this example)* is perfectly enough for the *decomposition* to work.

Enjoy...

---

### Correct Answer

° Notes

> - This ***answers the question asked 9 years ago***, *and*,
> - The ***solution*** proposed here uses ***only C++11 features***.
> - This solution manages ***only integral types***.
>   *(other type is let as an exercise for the reader)*
>
>   *If your compiler supports **C++17** features, the **solution posted above** should be preferred, as it manages **not only integral types**.*

*Only interested in a working code example?*
*jump to: "**Working Solutions**"*

° Preamble

> - **After my researches**, it seems that **a solution** to this particular problem **hasn't been found** *(or not published)* **until now**. I thought I should go in a little more details about the *"Whys"* and *"Hows"*. **I hope it will be** appreciated, but overall: **useful**...
> - I am currently in the process of writing a meta-programming library full of compile-time tools and features. I hope to be able to release it on GitHub anytime soon.
>   *(who knows) – Anyway*...
> - What hasn't been my frustration when I realized that my first answer was correct only since *C++17*... – *Not exactly "on time", one could say...:P*
> - With all the machinery of "compile-time only" features I have in mind ATM, I was feeling like there should have had a means to do that 9 years ago.
> - I begun to think about how I would have had done that using only *C++11* features and, after an hour or so, I found a *working solution*. *(two in fact)*
> - It took me a little more time to make it a *usable solution*. *(two in fact)*
> - And quite a bit more to right this post... *:D*
>
>   After all, there might have compilers
>   *"just good enough"* to understand *C++11 only*... *:P*

Obviously, as the set of features available at that time was narrower,
the solution found is *"**just a bit**"* more verbose... *:D*

° Searching Process

Firstly, one has to keep in mind that when a compiler outputs *"**cannot deduce**"*...
– It does not mean that there is an error *(though there might have one)*.
– It rather means that the compiler is not as clever as one thinks it is.
– It means that one has to give a hand to the compiler for it to be able to do its job...

In clear?
– The compiler is kindly asking for you to do a part of its job.
– And there's good chances for you:

- To end up doing most of the job yourself... *:P*

Here, the compiler says "cannot deduce the type of `T`".
Indeed, `T` is not used in the expression used as argument of the specialization of `foo`, and thus, it cannot be deduced from there...

One first has to do something to signify the relation between `typename T` and the value of `x` (which is of type `T`). What instantly comes to mind is that one needs a template similar to that of `std::integral_constant` which does exactly that. It encodes, into a ***new type***, a value along with its corresponding type.

> **Disclaimer** [! Warning! ]
>
> - People susceptible to develop allergic reactions at sight of uppercase letters within identifier names should not continue reading this post!

Nothing new until there?
Perfect! Here it is:

```
template<typename T, T V>
struct NonTypeParam { using Type = T; static constexpr T Value = V; };
```

Next one needs something to create instances of the `NonTypeParam` template with a value and its corresponding type...

- It might be a template taking a type parameter.
- This parameter would receive the type to decompose.
- Then, one would have to specialize it somehow...

Let's give it a try, and start with:

```
template<typename T> struct Extract { using Result = void; };
```

To fully abstract the specialization of the `Extract` template, one would have to write something like:

```
template<typename T, T V, template<T> class C>
struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = NonTypeParam<T, V>; };
```

Which leads to the same problem, because it is the same type of specialization used in the question. At that point, one has to remind what the compiler was unable to do. It *"**cannot deduce**"* what type the parameter `T` is supposed to alias in our specialization...

In fact, the message is misleading somehow, because `T` is not even part of the expression passed as argument of the specialization. Thus, the problem is not to attribute a `typename` to the parameter `T`, it is rather to attribute a *type* to the parameter `V`...
Now, one should be able to ask the right questions:

1. How can `T` be removed from the equation?

   - By explicitly defining the type of `V`.
2. What are the possible types for the value of `V`?

   - The types allowed as non-type template parameters.

First things first, how would look a specialization by explicitly defining the type of `V` for `char`, for example? It would look like that:

```
template<char V, template<char> class C>
struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = NonTypeParam<char, V>; };
```

, that's a little bit annoying, but as there is a finite number of possibilities. One might find a way to reduce the declarations later on. Let's add another specialization, a victim template, and put that to the test...

```
template<typename T, T V>
struct NonTypeParam { using Type = T; static constexpr T Value = V; };

template<typename T> struct Extract { using Result = void; };

template<char V, template<char> class C>
struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = NonTypeParam<char, V>; };

template<std::size_t V, template<std::size_t> class C>
struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = NonTypeParam<std::size_t, V>; };

template<std::size_t I> struct TestNonType1 {};

using Result          = typename Extract<TestNonType1<42>>::Result;
using RType           = typename Result::Type; // std::size_t
constexpr auto rValue = Result::Value;         // 42
```

No surprises, it works as expected...
... What are the possible types now?
According to the standard on [template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

> A non-type template parameter must have a structural type, which is one of the following types *(optionally cv-qualified, the qualifiers are ignored)*:
>
> - lvalue reference type (to object or to function);
> - an integral type;
> - a pointer type (to object or to function);
> - a pointer to member type (to member object or to member function);
> - an enumeration type;
> - std::nullptr_t; *(since C++11)*

For our case, the question asked for **integral types**.
Well, what does the standard says about integral types.
Let's have a look at [std::is_integral](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) to find out:

> ..., if `T` is the type `bool`, `char`, `char8_t` *(since C++20)*, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, or **any implementation-defined** extended **integer types**, including **any signed**, **unsigned**, and **cv-qualified** variants.

**Ouch!**

As there is 9 types – *if one exclude `char8_t` *(only from C++20)* and consider that implementation-defined integer types are most of the time aliases of these integral type* – one would have to do specializations for:

- 9 `signed`.
- 9 `signed const`.
- 9 `signed volatile`.
- 9 `signed const volatile`.
- Which does 36 specializations.
- And then, add 36 more for the unsigned versions?!

> **Disclaimer** [ Notice ]
>
> - Without a doubt, this is the reason why no one *(maybe really no one else)* did that before...

---

#### Wait, wait, wait a minute...

One should think about that a second time and, once again, ask the right questions:

- How is a non-type parameter *'read'*/*'interpreted'* ***?***
- Does it make any sense for it to be *`volatile`* ***?***
- If its value is part of the *`typename`*, isn't *`const`* implied somehow ***?***

*You certainly found the answers by yourself...*

– Likewise, there is **no *`unsigned`*** version of `char16_t`, `char32_t` and `wchar_t`.
– Moreover, if one reads a second time a little more carefully what the standard says about [template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), one might see something that haven't had the attention it deserves...

> *A non-type template parameter must have a structural type, which is one of the following types (optionally cv-qualified, ***the qualifiers are ignored***)*

*Well, well, well...*

– This will do ***a lot more job than*** one would have ***excepted*** at first... ***:P***
– It turn out that, in the end, **only 14 specializations** of the `Extract` template are enough to manage **99% of all possible integral types**...

... I think that's way too much writings for such a small amount of code.

Please find the solutions here below, – ***let here for the posterity*** – in hope it *might* be useful to someone *(at least for the interesting 'trickery' used in the second example)*.

° Personal Comment

> It is hard to me to believe that this 9 years old question haven't find an answer earlier *(as well as thinking that I would be the only "dumb" guy who found this answer)*

---

### Working Solutions

#### Solution #1

> Nothing special here. It's just a regular specialization of a template...

```
template<typename T, T V>
struct NonTypeParam { using Type = T; static constexpr T Value = V; };

namespace Details1 {

template<typename T> struct Extract { using Result = void; };

template<typename T, T V> using R = NonTypeParam<T, V>;

// boolean
template<bool V, template<bool> class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
// signed types
template<char      V, template<char>      class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
template<char16_t  V, template<char16_t>  class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
template<char32_t  V, template<char32_t>  class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
template<wchar_t   V, template<wchar_t>   class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
template<short     V, template<short>     class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
template<int       V, template<int>       class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
template<long      V, template<long>      class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
template<long long V, template<long long> class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
// unsigned types
template<unsigned char      V, template<unsigned char>      class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
template<unsigned short     V, template<unsigned short>     class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
template<unsigned int       V, template<unsigned int>       class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
template<unsigned long      V, template<unsigned long>      class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };
template<unsigned long long V, template<unsigned long long> class C> struct Extract<C<V>> { using Result = R<decltype(V), V>; };

} /* namespace Details1 */

template<typename T>
struct Extract1
{
    using Result = typename Details1::Extract<T>::Result;
};

// Victim template:
template<std::size_t I> struct TestNonType1 {};

// Usage:
using          Param  = typename Extract1<TestNonType1<42>>::Result;
using          PType  = typename Param::Type; // std::size_t
constexpr auto pValue = Param::Value;         // 42
```

#### Solution #2

> In this solution, one leverages the power of `decltype` to declare function template overloads, which will never be defined anywhere...

```
template<typename T, T V>
struct NonTypeParam { using Type = T; static constexpr T Value = V; };

namespace Details2 {

template<typename T, T V> using R = NonTypeParam<T, V>;

// boolean
template<bool V, template<bool> class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
// signed types
template<char      V, template<char>      class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
template<char16_t  V, template<char16_t>  class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
template<char32_t  V, template<char32_t>  class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
template<wchar_t   V, template<wchar_t>   class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
template<short     V, template<short>     class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
template<int       V, template<int>       class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
template<long      V, template<long>      class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
template<long long V, template<long long> class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
// unsigned types
template<unsigned char      V, template<unsigned char>      class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
template<unsigned short     V, template<unsigned short>     class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
template<unsigned int       V, template<unsigned int>       class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
template<unsigned long      V, template<unsigned long>      class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);
template<unsigned long long V, template<unsigned long long> class C> R<decltype(V), V> Extract(C<V> && _);

} /* namespace Details2 */

template<typename T>
struct Extract2
{
    using Result = decltype(Details2::Extract(std::declval<T>()));
};

// Victim template:
template<unsigned long long I> struct TestNonType2 {};

// Usage:
using          Param  = typename Extract2<TestNonType2<42>>::Result;
using          PType  = typename Param::Type; // std::size_t
constexpr auto pValue = Param::Value;         // 42
```

---

***° Update** (July 25, 2021)*

- Here below is an example of how a template declared with **any type** of non-type parameter can be decomposed.
- Unfortunately, though this little piece of code seems to be using only C++11 language features, it cannot be compiled as C++11.
- This code works perfectly, and does what it is meant to do, but is has to be compiled as C++17.
- There definitely had a change in the standard since the addition of `auto` as a non-type template parameter which, I think *(but couldn't find info on it)*, make the compilers interpret the pattern `<typename T, template <T> class C, T V>` as if it was a *synonym* of `<auto V>`.

```
/* Template allowing to separately retrieve the components
 * of a template having one non-type parameter.
 */
template<typename T, template <T> class C, T V>
struct TmplInfo;

/* Function to decompose a template having one non-type
 * parameter and return its corresponding TmplInfo type.
 */
template<typename T, template <T> class C, T V>
inline constexpr TmplInfo<T, C, V> ToTmplInfo(C<V> && o);

/* Our victim template...
 */
template<std::size_t I> struct Victim;

/* Aliases Victim<42> and then decompose it to a TmplInfo.
 */
using V42   = Victim<42>;
using VInfo = decltype(ToTmplInfo(std::declval<V42>()));

/* Compiled for x64 arch, this gives:
 * using VInfo = TmplInfo<std::size_t, Victim, 42Ui64>;
 */
```

Comment: Good to know this is possible now! Back when I asked in 2012, not all of these features existed.

Comment: @glaebhoerl You've posted your comment before my edit. It was, in fact, perfectly doable... ;) _(like the two examples show it)_

Comment: @glaebhoerl As a side note, it is to be noted that the pattern you used in 2012 is recognized and compiles fine in _C++17_... I think the compiler _"induces"_ the relation between _`typename T`_ and _`T x`_ as if _`x`_ was declared _`auto`_...

Comment: @glaebhoerl I don't know if it's part of the standard or if it is compiler-dependent. But when you think about it, it's very logical... As _`x`_ is used as a non-type parameter in the expression passed as attribute of the specialization, _`T`_ can only be a type _valid_ for a non-type parameter...

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you put into the edit! But FWIW, the original question was *not* just about integral types -- also pointers, member pointers, etc., which are valid as non-type template parameters. And since you can have pointers-to-pointers and so on, it is unfortunately not possible to finitely enumerate all of the possible types, you do need some kind of generic solution.

Comment: +1 @glaebhoerl for having taking the time to read it all for, in the end, realizing that it wasn't fully answering the original question... ;) I've certainly been a little too optimistic when I realized that only 14 specializations would do the job for almost all integral types, and I forgot to carefully reread the question... So, let's say that it isn't possible with _C++11_ or even _C++14_. But, in the library I'm developing currently, I've faced the same problem. I did an ambrosial of something which might give good results, but there's quite a bit of code, and, it uses _C++17_ features...

Comment: @glaebhoerl I've added an update note _(close to the top)_, and a code example at the end showing that, in fact, there was a way to handle _**any type**_ of non-type parameters _(already 9 years ago)_... ;)

Comment: Hmm, are you sure? I got excited for a moment, but when I tried it out I still get "couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘T’".

Comment: @glaebhoerl I feel a little ashamed, I have to say. I made another edit to rectify the statement... After having gave it another try _(once again)_ I've been able to advance a little and did something for _integral pointer types_ that works. I also have tracks on how to make it work for functions, but there seems to have no way to make the compiler deduce the type of a pointer to a class type... ;( – This means that there seems to have no chance to make it work for _pointers to member variables/functions_, and, this is giving an end to this journey, I think...

Comment: Well, kudos for the super thorough examination in either case :)

Answer (score 2):

This other question is asking basically the same thing but for template *type* parameters, rather than template *non-type* parameters: [template metaprogramming: (trait for?) dissecting a specified template into types T<T2,T3 N,T4, ...>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723652/template-metaprogramming-trait-for-dissecting-a-specified-template-into-type)

For *type* parameters, it really is easy. The code looks like this:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template <class T> struct explode;

template <template <class... Args> class T, class... N>
struct explode<T<N...>>
{
    typedef T<N...> type;
    template <class... Args> using template_ = T<Args...>;
    template <int I> using type_parameter =
        typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<N...>>::type;
};

#if TESTING
void test_harness()
{
    typedef explode<std::vector<int>> exv;

    exv::template_<char> vchar;  // The second parameter still has its default argument!
    exv::template_<exv::type_parameter<0>, exv::type_parameter<1>> vint;

    static_assert(std::is_same<exv::template_<char>, std::vector<char>>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(vchar), std::vector<char>>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(vint), std::vector<int>>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<exv::type, std::vector<int>>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<exv::type_parameter<0>, int>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<exv::type_parameter<1>, std::allocator<int>>::value, "");
}
#endif
```

But for *non-type* parameters, I haven't figured out if it's possible yet. You can start with the similar-looking code

```
template <class... ArgTypes, template <ArgTypes... Args> class T, ArgTypes... N>
struct explode<T<N...>>
{
    typedef T<N...> type;
    template <ArgTypes... Args> using template_ = T<Args...>;
    template <int I> using type_of_parameter =
        typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<ArgTypes...>>::type;
    template <int I> struct nontype_parameter {
        static constexpr type_of_parameter<I> value() {
            return std::get<I>(std::tuple<ArgTypes...>(N...));
        }
    };
};
```

};

but Clang (at least) doesn't accept it:

```
test.cc:8:8: warning: class template partial specialization contains a template
      parameter that can not be deduced; this partial specialization will never
      be used
struct explode<T<N...>>
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:7:20: note: non-deducible template parameter 'ArgTypes'
template <class... ArgTypes, template <ArgTypes... Args> class T, ArgTypes... N>
                   ^
```

and even if you made that problem go away somehow, you'd still have to replace `std::get` with a hand-coded `constexpr` version, because the standard library's `std::get` isn't `constexpr` for whatever reason.

Comment: Yep, that's basically the same problem I ran into with my first example. If a template parameter is present only in the template parameter list but not in the specialization arguments, it can't be inferred. Presumably the standard mandates this, because otherwise it doesn't look like something that would be impossible.