# template metaprogramming: (trait for?) dissecting a specified template into types T<T2,T3 N,T4, ...>

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I'm trying to deduce the underlying template type `T` from a type `E = T<T2,T3>`. This would for example make it possible to make a template function pair_maker(const E & a) which can be used with one of several similar types of containers. Rough meta code:

```
template <typename T>
auto pairmaker(const E & a) -> PairContents<E,std::string>::type {
    ContainerPairMaker<E,std::string>::type output;
    ... some code ...
    return output;
}
```

`PairContents<E,std::string>`

would transform the type `vector<int>` into `vector<pair(int,std::string)>` or `whatever<T1>` into `whatever<pair(T1,std::string)>`.

Another similar example of type dissection is for std::array (or similar containers) where I like to figure out the *container* type to make a new similar array. For example for these kind of functions (this is actual working code now)

```
template <typename T > 
auto make_some3(const T & a) 
           -> std::array<typename T::value_type,10*std::tuple_size<T>::value>{   
   return std::array<typename T::value_type,10*std::tuple_size<T>::value>{} ;
}
```

This works fine but what I'm after is to make the explicit use of 'std::array' automatic.

For std::array there's the tuple_size trait which helps, and a similar thing can be used to find the `type` for any second argument, but again I can't think of anything for finding the container type.

To summarize: what kind of machinery (if any) can be used for cases like these. To which extent is it possible to deal with mixes of template arguments, template-template arguments, any number of arguments, and non-template arguments of unknown types.

Comment: Problem is, if you *only* rebind the first parameter, standard containers will have a mismatching allocator, aka `PairContent<vector<int, allocator<int>>,float>::type` will be `vector<pair<int,float>, allocator<int>>`.

Comment: As a point of terminology, in `T<T2, T3>` `T` is not a type. What you're looking for is the underlying class template `T` of which `T<T2, T3>` is a specialization (and a type). Hence you can't have `extract<std::vector<int>>::type` be `std::vector`.

Comment: Xeo, Ohh... That's a huge issue. Why don't you bring that into your now deleted answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
 template <typename T, typename ...>
 struct tmpl_rebind
 {
     typedef T type;
 };

 template <template <typename ...> class Tmpl, typename ...T, typename ...Args>
 struct tmpl_rebind<Tmpl<T...>, Args...>
 {
     typedef Tmpl<Args...> type;
 };
```

Usage:

```
typedef std::vector<int> IV;
typedef typename tmpl_rebind<IV, std::pair<double, std::string>>::type PV;
```

Now `PV = std::vector<std::pair<double, std::string>>`.

Comment: I had no idea specified templates could be passed as template template arguments.

Comment: @JohanLundberg They can't -- if you think of matching a template specialization as pattern matching, then here the template specialization is deconstructed into its primary template and template parameters parts. Look at the primary template declaration of `tmpl_rebind`: the first argument (`typename T`) is in fact a template type argument, not a template template argument.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: That isn't my answer, I only edited a certain part of it. ;)

Comment: @JohanLundberg This answer doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Xeo, Ah, yes I just mistyped and swapped your names. @Xeo, Kerrek, Luc, thank you for these comments. All right, in this case all arguments are rebound, so there's no old allocating in there. I see it now. typeid(PV) == typeid(PV2)

Comment: @Xeo, KerrekSB, I found I liked a slight variant of this solution, I posted it as a self answer for reference.

Answer (score 4):

**This is a self answer I came up with as a variant of the answer from Kerrek SB**

It is possible to make a trait that extracts `std::vector` from `std::vector<int>` and exposes it as `::type` via a trait. Yes, this solution is nearly identical to Kerrek's, but to me the use syntax is more aesthetic, putting the template parameters after `::type`.

```
template <typename T, typename ...>
struct retemplate
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <template <typename ...> class Tmpl, typename ...T>
struct retemplate<Tmpl<T...>>
{
   template <typename ...AR>
   using type=Tmpl<AR...> ;
};
```

with this you actually get `retemplate<T<A,B,C>>::type` equal to the template `T`

example use:

```
typedef std::vector<int> intvec; 
typedef retemplate<intvec>::type<double> doublevec;
```

or to expose the container type

```
typedef std::vector<int> intv;
template <typename ...T>
using vector_T= retemplate<intv>::type<T...> ;
```

Note that when using this in template context, an extra `template` is required just after `::`, like this: (elaborating on the comment from Xeo)

```
template <typename T>
typename retemplate<T>::template type<double> containedDouble(T& a) {
   decltype(containedDouble(a)) out;
   for (auto &i : a)
      out.push_back(i);
   return out;
}
```

What that does is to take an object of type `T1<T2>` and copy its content into a `T1<double>`. For example with `T1==std::vector` and `T2==int`.

Comment: The calling snytax gets *slightly* ugly inside template code, though: `typename retemplate<intv>::template type<T...>`.

Comment: This is nice. I haven't quite got used to the new `using`s yet :-)

Comment: @Xeo: Why do you have to say `template`? There's no dependent name there, is there -- `intv` is an actual type.

Comment: @Kerrek: Inside a template, you'd need to (and obviously replace `intv` with a template parameter, my fail).

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, indeed, if you're inside a dependent context, of course. Cheers. Anyway, who doesn't love saying `::template` a lot to impress the boss?

Comment: @KerrekSB, that's hilarious, not sure impress is the right word. But really, I never would have figured out to put `template ` between `::` and `type`.

Comment: yes this new `using` template typedef shortens the meta bloat nicely. before we had to declare new template structs which would define a ::type of thmeselves. inheritance from the nesting class never worked for a reason I still don't grasp. thus the new `using` saves 3 lines. and a struct keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend taking a look at **A. Alexandrescu**'s book **Modern C++ Design**.

If I recall correctly he explains how one might use **type lists** to store and access arbitrary types in a list-like fashion. These lists can be used to provide type information in a number of different situations. Take a look at the implementation of [**Loki**](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) to see how type lists can be utilized.

I'm not sure if this is helpful at all, but maybe you can learn something from the ideas used in Loki in order to solve or at least better understand your specific issues at hand.