# C++ class template is a template: template argument is invalid

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem with a class template. I want the private data in a class to be a vector of vectors of some kind of numeric type, i.e:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> >
std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<double> > >
```

But I want the type of vector (I'm using a library of third party vectors along with stl vectors), and the element type to be templated. I tried template templates but now I don't think that is the solution to my problem. A highly simplified example is:

```
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
template<typename T>
class Fred {
    std::vector<T> data_;
};
int main(){
    Fred<std::vector<double> > works;
    //Fred<std::vector<std::complex<double> > doesnt_work;
    return 0;
}
```

As shown it compiles fine, but if I uncomment the second line in main, I get the error (g++ 4.6):

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

Why do I get this error? And does anyone have a suggested fix?
Thanks!

Comment: Count the `<`s and the `>`s in the line that doesn't work. There's one missing...

Comment: That is a really poor error message, completely misleading.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Shame. I was getting ready to dig up my [template rebinder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11723847/596781).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
template<typename T>
class Fred {
    std::vector<T> data_;
};

int main(){
    //Fred<std::vector<double> > works;
    Fred<std::vector<std::complex<double> > > doesnt_work;
    return 0;
}
```

Works well. You miss third `>` in declaration of `doesnt_work`.

Comment: if only the compiler could just know it as a missing bracket, rather than printing a thousand line error message - which btw completely meaningless