# Is it possible to define an alias for a template-template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-templates

I'm experimenting with template-template for fun. I have the following class:

```
template<template<class> class T, typename R> class Unit
{    
    using FullType = T<R>;
    using Ratio = R;
    //using Type = T;

    ...
};
```

I have define type `R` and `T<R>` as member-types `Ratio` and `FullType`.
Is it possible to alias `T` as `Type` ?

The commented line above give me the following errors on g++ 4.7:

```
expected nested-name-specifier before 'Type'
using-declaration for non-member at class scope
expected ';' before '=' token
expected unqualified-id before '=' token
```

I tried some more or less random syntaxes, but none of them compiled.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make an alias for `T`. The following was discussed in the committee to make an alias for `T` (because a very late C++11 draft contained notes that stated that it *is* an alias for `T` which a [Defect Report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1244) cleaned up).

```
// Courtesy of @KerrekSB
template <template <typename> class T, typename R> class Unit
{
    template <typename U> using MyTemplate = T<U>;
    // ...

    // use e.g. MyTemplate<int> to get T<int>
};
```

Note while `MyTemplate<int>` is the same type as `T<int>`, that `MyTemplate` is **not** the same as `T`. The wording at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286 was supposed to change that, but in the last meeting it was considered to be a very special machinery that doesn't really fit what alias templates turned out to be (own templates), and it was pushed back to review. To get that effect, a `using MyTemplate = T;` in future may fit the bill (if proposed and accepted, of course).

Answer (score 4):

Since `T` isn't a type, the question as asked doesn't make sense. However, you can make an alias for `T`, like:

```
template <template <typename> class T, typename R> class Unit
{
    template <typename U> using MyTemplate = T<U>;
    // ...

    // use e.g. MyTemplate<int> to get T<int>
};
```

Pre-C++11 you would need something more notationally involved as outlined [in this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11723847/596781) (and used, for example, in the standard library by the standard allocator's `rebind` mechanic.)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.I'll edit the question in order for it to make sense