# An alternative for C++ not allowing templated type aliases?

Tags: c++, using, type-deduction, partial-specialization, template-templates

Imagine a library has class templates `A` and `B`:

```
template <template <class> class T> class A;
template  <class T, class U> class B;
```

Now, if a user of the library wants to pass B as an argument of A, he/she can do:

```
template <class T>
using C = B<T, UserType>;
A<C> a{};
```

However, `B` might actually have much more template and template template arguments, which would make this extremely ugly on the user side: every time a user would want to use `A` with different type, he/she would have to do that huuuge type aliasing and then use a different name for each different type. That is obviously not an option.
Is it thus possible for the implementers of such library to allow a user to do:

```
A<D<UserType>> a{};
```

where `D` would be "deduced" to be `template <class T> B<T, UserType>`.
Conceptually, the implementers should do:

```
template <class UserType>
using D = template <class T> B<T, UserType>;
```

and then `D` could be passed as a template argument to `A` as `A<D<UserType>>`. However, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896509/is-it-possible-to-define-an-alias-for-a-template-template-parameter), this does not compile.

Is there a way for the implementers to allow users to do both `A<C>` and `A<[B, UserType]>`, where brackets denote some operation with `B` and `UserType` that is implemented on the library side? Obviously, the implementers could use different names such as `A1` and `A2` but they do not want to since `A1` and `A2` would do the same thing and work in the same way.

Comment: Maybe you're API design is showing too much of your library internals. How would your client like to interact with your client. Do you have a clear idea what customization points your library needs to have? Maybe it is enough if a client injects a class implementing a few specific operations instead of being of a specific class. (static polymorphism). So maybe you can explain what you are trying to achieve, because I agree with you the API should be clean and easy to use (the kind of complexity you show should not be there or at least internal to the library)

Comment: Anyway I usually find if things get too complex somewhere I probably need to take a step back and look at my design again ;)

Comment: You can do this using a member template `inner` of a class template `D`, to allow `A<D<UserType>::inner>`.

Answer (score 6):

You're describing something like `D<UserType>` as something that is a template itself, where `D<UserType><T>` (imaginary syntax) is `B<T, UserType>`.

This is not possible, but you can get close by having a member template, `D<UserType>::member<T>`

```cpp
template<template<class...> class Template, class... U>
struct template_bind_back {
    template<typename... T>
    using type = Template<T..., U...>;
};


A<template_bind_back<B, UserType>::type>
```

Comment: The problem is that the library user needs to write that extra `::type` when for all other policies it passes to `A` he doesn't. I was hoping for cleaner API if possible.