# Is it possible to check if a object is equal to a template class without specifying the template type?

Tags: c++, class, templates, types, typeid

Suppose I have the class:

```
template<typename T>
class ChartData {
public:
...
```

Now I want to check if the object `value` is a ChartData object:

```
if (value.type() == typeid(ChartData*))
```

However this causes the error

> argument list for class template is missing

So the compiler is expecting me to put a type at `ChartData*` however in this condition I'm not interested in the type - I just want to know if the object is a instance of a ChartData object.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Not at runtime, no. But what about a base class for youtr template?

Comment: There *are* no instances of `ChartData`, because `ChartData` is not a type – it's a template for creating types. The instantiations of the template are types, but they are as unrelated as if you had written them out by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
template <typename T>
struct IsChartData : public std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct IsChartData<ChartData<T>> : public std::true_type {};

if (IsChartData<decltype(value)>()) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use template meta programming

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class, template<class...> class>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template<template<class...> class temp, class... tempargs>
struct is_specialization<temp<tempargs...>, temp> : std::true_type {};

template<class>
struct dummy {};
int main () {
    dummy<int> d;
    static_assert(is_specialization<decltype (d), dummy>::value);
}
```

This works for all templates with only type template arguments. If you have mixed type and non-type this is not really doable in a general way but you can of course write the above for one specific template and the fitting arguments.

Comment: At the risk of blowing my own trumpet, I [challenge your assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396786/check-if-class-is-a-template-specialization/55398444#55398444) ;)

Comment: You are a sick genius.