# Template metaprogramming help: transforming a vector

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

As my first template metaprogram I am trying to write a function that transforms an input vector to an output vector.

For instance, I want

```
vector<int> v={1,2,3};
auto w=v_transform(v,[](int x){return (float)(x*2)})
```

to set w to the vector of three floats, `{2.0, 4.0, 6.0}` .

I started with this stackoverflow question, [The std::transform-like function that returns transformed container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871757/the-stdtransform-like-function-that-returns-transformed-container?rq=1) , which addresses a harder question of transforming arbitrary containers.

I now have two solutions:

1. A solution, `v_transform_doesntwork` that doesn’t work, but I don’t know why (which I wrote myself).
2. A solution, `v_transform` that works, but I don’t know why (based on Michael Urman's answer to the above question)

I am looking for simple explanations or pointers to literature that explains what is happening.

Here are the two solutions, `v_transform_doesntwork` and `v_transform`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename Functor,
    typename U=typename std::result_of<Functor(T)>::type>
vector<U> v_transform(const std::vector<T> &v, Functor&& f){
    vector<U>ret;
    for(const auto & e:v)
        ret.push_back(f(e));
    return ret;
}

template<typename T, typename U> 
vector<U> v_transform_doesntwork(const std::vector<T> &v, U(*f)(const T &)){
    vector<U>ret;
    for(const auto & e:v)
        ret.push_back(f(e));
    return ret;
}

float foo(const int & i){
    return (float)(i+1);
}

int main(){
    vector<int>v{1,2,3,4,5};
    auto w=v_transform(v,foo);
    auto z=v_transform(v,[](const int &x){return (float)(x*2);});
    auto zz=v_transform(v,[](int x){return (float)(x*3);});
    auto zzz=v_transform_doesntwork(v,[](const int &x){return (float)(x*2);});
}
```

**Question 1**: why doesn’t the call to `v_transform_doesntwork` compile? (It gives a fail-to-match template error, c++11. I tried about 4 permutations of “const” and “&” and “*” in the argument list, but nothing seemed to help.)

I prefer the implementation of `v_transform_doesntwork` to that of `v_transform`, because it’s simpler, but it has the slight problem of not working.

**Question 2**: why does the call to `v_transform` work? I get the gist obviously of what is happening, but I don’t understand why all the typenames are needed in defining U, I don’t understand how this weird syntax of defining a template parameter that is relied on later in the same definition is even allowed, or where this is all specified. I tried looking up "dependent type names" in cppreference but saw nothing about this kind of syntax.

Further note: I am assuming that `v_transform` works, since it compiles. If it would fail or behave unexpectedly under some situations, please let me know.

Comment: Closures aren't function pointers. They may be *convertible* to them, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: then why isn't it converted?

Comment: If you can rely on C++11, take a look at trailing-return-type and `decltype`. They will make your life much easier.

Comment: @kdog: To get converted you'd need to say which type to convert it to, but you don't have that situation, because instead you chose to ask for template argument deduction. Argument deduction doesn't then also consider user-defined conversions (that would never work if you think about it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `doesnotwork` expects a function pointer and pattern matches on it.

A lambda is not a function pointer.  A stateless lambda can be converted to a function pointer, but template pattern matching does not use conversions (other than a very limited subset -- `Derived&` to `Base&` and `Derived*` to `Base&`, reference-to-value and vice versa, etc -- never a constructor or conversion operator).

Pass `foo` to `doesnotwork` and it should work, barring typos in your code.

```
template<typename T, 
  typename Functor,
  typename U=typename std::result_of<Functor(T)>::type
>
vector<U> v_transform(const std::vector<T> &v, Functor&& f){
  vector<U>ret;
  for(const auto & e:v)
    ret.push_back(f(e));
  return ret;
}
```

so you call `v_transform`.  It tries to deduce the template types.

It pattern matches the first argument.  You pass a `std::vector<int, blah>` where `blah` is some allocator.

It sees that the first argument is `std::vector<T>`.  It matches `T` to `int`.  As you did not give a second parameter, the default allocator for `std::vector<T>` is used, which happens to match `blah`.

We then continue to the second parameter.  You passed in a closure object, so it deduces the (unnamable) lambda type as `Functor`.

It is now out of arguments to pattern match.  The remaining types use their defaulted types -- `U` is set to `typename std::result_of<Functor(T)::type`.  This does not result in a substitution failure, so SFINAE does not occur.

All types are determined, and the function is now slotted into the set of overloads to examine to determine which to call.  As there are no other functions of the same name, and it is a valid overload, it is called.

---

Note that your code has a few minor errors:

```
template<typename T, 
  typename A,
  typename Functor,
  typename U=typename std::decay<typename std::result_of<Functor&(T const&)>::type>::type
>
std::vector<U> v_transform(const std::vector<T, A> &v, Functor&& f){
  std::vector<U> ret;
  ret.reserve(v.size());
  for(const auto & e:v)
    ret.push_back(f(e));
  return ret;
}
```

which cover some corner cases.

Comment: Wow that is very clear and helpful. How/where do you learn all this? It just seems like people just know it from the ether. I don't need to worry about custom allocs in my app, but can you explain what is the point of changing Functor to Functor& in the argument to result_of?

Comment: @kdog If you pass an rvalue functor (like you do in the OP) to the function, then `Functor` is the class type (with no reference), and `std::result_of<Functor(T)>` invokes the rvalue `operator()` overload.  You, however, use it in an lvalue context within the transform.  In an extreme corner case, this will screw up.  Oh, that reminds me, another problem -- we need to `decay`!  And where do I know it?  More than a decade of coding in C++, playing with the language, reading the standard (in short bits!), learning from various sources, and the like.

Comment: @Yakk wow -- I definitely wouldn't have caught the decay bug... impressive!

Comment: Very interesting, but I am curious what case would (a) fail if Functor& were changed to Functor in the result_of expression; (b) fail if the std::decay call were omitted?

Comment: @kdog if your function object returned a reference, you cannot store references in vectors, so the body will fail.  Similarly if a function returned a `const` object.  `decay` can be used to convert types to 'storable' types.  The `Functor&` would basically require a function object with a different `operator()&&` and `operator()&` overload, at this point a ridiculous corner case: in addition (after said decay) it would have to be a very strangely different overload (`operator()&` returning a ref, while `operator()&&` returning a value, is ... more common).

Comment: @kdog: You learn it by doing lots of C++, paying attention to the problems and surprises you encounter, reading explanations on Stack Overflow, checking standard references yourself, and then iterate on this whole thing and never stop :-)

Comment: @Yakk thanks again for the great answer. Extremely helpful and illuminating not just for this specific issue but for later work with template metaprogramming.

Answer (score 2):

#### Question 1

*Why doesn't the call to `v_transform_doesntwork` compile?*

This is because you've passed it a C++11 lambda. The template argument in `v_transform_doesntwork` is a function pointer argument. C++11 lambdas are, in fact, *objects* of an unknown type. So the declaration

```
template<typename T, typename U>
vector<U> v_transform_doesntwork(const std::vector<T> &v, U(*f)(const T &))
```

binds T to the input type of the function pointer `f` and `U` to the output type of the function pointer. But the second argument cannot accept a lambda for this reason! You can specify the types explicitly to make it work with the *non-capturing* lambda, but the compiler will not attempt the type inference in the face of the cast.

#### Question 2

*Why does the call to `v_transform` work?*

Let's look at the code you wrote:

```
template<typename T, 
typename Functor,
typename U=typename std::result_of<Functor(T)>::type>
vector<U> v_transform(const std::vector<T> &v, Functor&& f){
```

Again, `T` is a template parameter that represents the input type. But now `Functor` is a parameter for whichever callable object you decide to pass in to `v_transform` (nothing special about the name). We set `U` to be equal to the **result** of that `Functor` being called on `T`. The `std::result_of` function jumps through some hoops to figure out what the return value will be. You also might want to change the definition of `U` to

```
typename U=typename std::result_of<Functor&(T const &)>::type>
```

so that is can accept functions taking constants or references as parameters.

Comment: Why Functor&(T const &) and not Functor(T const &) ?

Comment: actually hold on...i don't even see why Functor(T) could have a different result than Functor(T const &). I mean, if the Functor parameter is declared as const T&, and a T argument is passed in, then the invocation will still return the type U. Maybe if Functor were overloaded to do something different if it gets a const T& versus a T actual parameter at the invoking site?

Comment: @kdog yes, if the function object did something different with a `T` or a `T const&` argument.

Answer (score 0):

For the `doesntwork` function, you need to explicitly specify the template parameters:

```
auto zzz=v_transform_doesntwork<int,float>(v,[](const int &x){return (float)(x*2);});
```

Then it does work.  The compiler is not able to implicitly determine these parameters whilst it converts the lambda to a function pointer.