# Compiler does not deduce template parameters (map std::vector -> std::vector)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector, std

I have the following template.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::vector<U> map(const std::vector<T> &v, std::function<U(const T&)> f) {
    std::vector<U> res;
    res.reserve(v.size());
    std::transform(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::end(res), f);
    return res;
}
```

When I use it in my code I have the specify the template parameters. Why is the compiler not able to deduce this for me? How do I have to change my template definition to make this work?

```
vector<int> numbers = { 1, 3, 5 };

// vector<string> strings = map(numbers, [] (int x) { return string(x,'X'); });

vector<string> strings = map<int, string>(numbers, [] (int x) { return string(x,'X'); });
```

Runnable code: http://ideone.com/FjGnxd

The original code in this question comes from here: [The std::transform-like function that returns transformed container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871757/the-stdtransform-like-function-that-returns-transformed-container)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your function expects an `std::function` argument, but you're calling it with a lambda expression instead. The two are not the same type. A lambda is *convertible* to `std::function`, but template argument deduction requires exact matches and user defined conversions are not considered. Hence the deduction failure.

Deduction does work if you actually pass an `std::function` to `map()`.

```
std::function<string(int const&)> fn = [] (int x) { return string(x,'X'); };
vector<string> strings = map(numbers, fn);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dc0544d66a246be)

---

One possible workaround to avoid having to specify the template arguments is to modify the function to accept any kind of callable, rather than an `std::function` object.

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
std::vector<typename std::result_of<Func(T)>::type>
    map(const std::vector<T> &v, Func f) {
        // ...
    }
```

Another version of the same idea, using `decltype` and `declval` instead of `result_of`

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
std::vector<decltype(std::declval<Func>()(std::declval<T>()))>
    map(const std::vector<T> &v, Func f) {
        // ...
    }
```

Finally, using a trailing return type

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
auto map(const std::vector<T> &v, Func f) 
  -> std::vector<decltype(f(v[0]))> {
        // ...
    }
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82fa4f03468912b7)

Comment: Usually, `typename std::result_of<Func(T)>::type` shows up in multiple places inside the `map` function. You cannot typedef it to make it shorter, but is their a way to create an alias for it so there is no repetition?

Comment: @Ferenc If you have C++14, it can be shortened to `std::result_of_t<Func(T)>`. Or you can write your own `template<typename T> using result_of_t = typename result_of<T>::type;`